# weblogic fail to start: Address already in use error

Tags: eclipse, weblogic

I have a test application that I created to start learn weblogic with Eclipse . 
yesterday  the jsp page was working well when I run as / on server , I got the basic page that I created .
but today I have an error message :

> FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
>   ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
>   ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
>   JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]

in the browser I got this :

> Error 404--Not Found 
>   From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
>   10.4.5 404 Not Found
>   The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.

and an other time I got this on console :

> weblogic.application.ModuleException: null
>   null
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.createModuleException(WebAppModule.java:1824)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:270)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:682)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.init(ScopedModuleDriver.java:162)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.init(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:98)
>       Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

can you explain to me what I miss , when I start the server it has the status started . thank you I can add any information .

Comment: `Address already in use ERROR` probably means the port is already opened. Add your debugging configuration to the question.

Comment: excuse my newbie question : what is debugging configuration mean ?

Comment: You should have something like this in your JVM/server config : `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=9000, suspend=n`. That `address` defines the port the jvm will be listening for debug clients like Eclipse.

Comment: I found this line in setDomainEnv  SH file :  set JAVA_DEBUG=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=%DEBUG_PORT%,server=y,suspend=n -Djava.compiler=NONE

Comment: it s looks don t have that values

Comment: So, you need your `DEBUG_PORT` env variable set.

Comment: how can I do that please ? can you give more details .

Comment: Investigate how to set an environment variable for your OS, Linux, Windows, Mac, etc. OR just replace `%DEBUG_PORT%` with a fixed number, e.g. 9005.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause is server running in debug mode and having the same debug port as an existing server on same machine.

If you have multiple domains configured for each domain running in development mode on the same machine make sure DEBUG_PORT in the *setDomainEnv* script has different values.

If you have multiple managed servers on the same domain and same machine, create a separate *startManagedWeblogic* script to start your managed servers and set the Debug Port in that script.

If you use Node Manager to start your managed servers, make sure you have the following lines set in your *nodemanager.properties* file, otherwise etDomainEnv.sh won't be executed:

```
StartScriptEnabled=true
StopScriptEnabled=true
```

This way, if you start the Managed Server via the Admin Console, *setDomainEnv.sh* will get called.

Then, you can modify the WebLogic domain script *setDomainEnv.sh* to set the proper `DEBUG_PORT` value according to the server name that needs to be started:

Use your favourite editor to change the setDomainEnv.sh file

You should find the following lines already :

```
if [ "${SERVER_NAME}" = "" ] ; then
    SERVER_NAME="AdminServer"
    export SERVER_NAME
fi
```

The same way, you can add :

```
if [ "${SERVER_NAME}" = "ManagedServer1" ] ; then
   DEBUG_PORT="8454"
   export DEBUG_PORT
fi   

if [ "${SERVER_NAME}" = "ManagedServer2" ] ; then
   DEBUG_PORT="8455"
   export DEBUG_PORT
fi
```